# TMP (Template meta-programming) with Eigen: A simple * binary operator does not compile with an extended Eigen::Matrix type

Tags: c++11, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, eigen3

Following the example for extension of `Eigen::Types` [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html) on **Inheriting From Matrix**, I created the following, a slight variation of the example:

```
class MyType : public Eigen::Vector3d {
public:
  MyType(void) : Eigen::Vector3d() {}
  template<typename OtherDerived> // MyType ctor from Eigen expressions
  MyType(const Eigen::MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& other)
    : Eigen::Vector3d(other) {}

  // ... operator= as in the example, not shown to save some space ...

  // ONLY NEW CODE: a new binary operator ^ returning Matrix3d
  template<typename OtherDerived>
  Eigen::Matrix3d operator^ (const Eigen::MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& other) {
    return Eigen::Matrix3d{ *this * other.transpose() };
  }
};
```

The new binary operator `^` does its job only conditionally as shown below:

```
MyType t1; t1.setRandom(); std::cout << "t1 is:\n" << t1 << std::endl;
MyType t2; t2.setRandom(); std::cout << "t2 is:\n" << t2 << std::endl;

Eigen::Matrix3d t3 = t1 ^ t2; std::cout << "t3 is:\n" << t3 << std::endl; // works
const double fac1{ 10.0 }; // invoke using multiplication factors
t3 = t1 ^ t2*fac1; // and t1 ^ fac1*t2 also works, output is correct

t3 = t1*fac1 ^ t2; // does not compile. Neither does t1*fac1 ^ t2.
```

I can use the standard `*` binary operator with a scalar and a `Vector3d` as operands (supported by **Eigen**). But it works only on the second operand of my new `^` binary operator. Based on the operator precedence, and perhaps some ADL (argument-dependent lookup), I expect the compiler to sort them out. Now here is the compiler error message (in code style for readability):

```
myCode.cpp(43) : error C2676: binary '^' :
  'const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_multiple_op<double>,const Derived>'
  does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the 
  predefined operator with
    [   Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,3,1,0,3,1>    ]
```

Am I to infer that the compiler thinks somehow `*` in `t1*fac1` is a unary operator? How come this was not a problem when it was applied on `t2` whose type is exactly the same as that of `t1`. Tried enclosing between parantheses so: `(fac1*t1) ^ t2`, but did not work. I also defined my own `operator* (const double&)` with a scalar and `MyType` as operands, but the above line of code had exactly the same compilation error.

Could this be an `Eigen` or a compiler bug? I am using MS Visual C++ 2015.
Am I missing something simple? Any light you can shed on the issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to extend Eigen's API is not by subclassing `Matrix` but by either adding methods to Eigen's `DenseBase`, `MatrixBase`, or `Matrix` classes via the [plugin mechanism](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicCustomizing_Plugins.html) or by implementing templated free functions. In your case, the last option is the simplest. With Eigen 3.3:

```
template<typename A,typename B>
Product<A,Transpose<const B> >
operator^(const MatrixBase<A> &a,const MatrixBase<B> &b) {
  return a * b.transpose();
}
```

And you're done.

Comment: Thanks @ggael. That works perfectly, although I had to make some changes, could be because I am using 3.2.9 (didn't want to risk using 3.3-rc1 as a first time user of Eigen). I had to do `typename ProductReturnType< ... >::Type` for the return type expression. Not only did your answer resolve my problem, but it made me *understand the MP part of TMP*, much better now!! While it might be some more work, I think implementing it through the plugin mechanism makes the feature readily available in my application, don't you think? I am new to SE, I hope my "acceptance of answer" shows up.

Comment: in my original post I chose `Vector3d` operands deliberately. My final goal is to be able to perform `M = c1*M1 ^ c2*M2 //c1,c2` are scalar coefficients. The matrices `M1,M2` are like `<double,nR,nC>` and the returned matrix is a dyadic product of each column of `M1` with the same column of `M2` so that `M` is like `<double,nR*nR,nC>`. All, expressions should generate the usual efficient, unrolled, vectorized code. I am not interested in the returned `M` being `<double,nR,nR>` after this product. Is it possible to construct this expression? I realize this is a different question from OP. Thx.

Comment: I guess M is `nR*nC x nC`? If I understood correctly the question, then you could try with replicate and a manual reshape of m2: `c1*c2*m1.array().replicate(nC,1).colwise() * Map<ArrayXd>(m2.data(),nR*nC)`.

Comment: No M is `nR*nR x nC`, which is the returned matrix from the operator function which wraps around your function. I got it to working by looping over columns of M1 (or M2) in this wrapper. The inner function returns a matrix `nR x nR` for each column, and so I `Eigen::Map` into kC column thus: `&M(0,kC)`. I have two variants just to test out the performance - both work with expressions like `c1*M1 ^ c2*M2`, so I can chain them. Is there a way to obtain vectorization report for generated code? It would be nice to make my decision based on that. Thx @ggael for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem abstractly might be as follows. In the first case that works, t2*fac1 evaluates first and returns a temporary object of some base type and then the ^ operator is invoked with *t2* as *this* which is of type MyType and the second argument is the temporary value. In the second case however, you have t1*fac1 evaluated first and returns an object of some base type as well but this time it is trying to invoke operator ^ on that base type object which according to you is not implemented in such base type.

you said that you implemented the operator * with double and MyType as operands, was that a class member operator? maybe you can try something like that and make sure that this operator is called in both cases not the one in the base class:

```
MyType operator*(const double&); // MyType as a member operator.
```

Comment: The base type is `Eigen::Matrix` and it **supports** a binary `*` with a scalar double type, as evidenced by simple operations such as `a1*m1 + a2*m2` where `a1,a2` are doubles and `m1,m2` are `Matrix` types. Remember my error is NOT a runtime one, it is purely a compiler error. Even if the temporary would be a base type and not `MyType`, the compiler should be able to cast it, based on the expression being evaluated, right?

Comment: I will answer point by point. 1- I understand that the operator* in the base class supports the scalar multiplication but I'm saying that it will return a different type from MyType 2- Given that it will NOT return MyType (the only type that supports operator ^) then you can NOT invoke operator ^ from the base type and that should result in a compile not runtime error. 3- I'm not really sure about such compiler casting. (a Downcast/Sidecast must use dynamic casting, I think c style castings would work as well)

Comment: Forgot about your class member operator - that's exactly what I have. The only thing that *works* is a static_cast to MyType, but that *goes against writing elegant expressions*. Still thanks for the answer. I would like to investigate further and see if I can fix it with my code, and not expect clients to perform any casting. I was using "compiler casting" in a loose sense: the compiler has to generate code based on the *expression* tree it builds, and it is possible that it loses the connection between the type of `t1` and type of `t1*fac1`.

Comment: You can implement also a free function in your class as follows  template<typename OtherDerived>   Eigen::Matrix3d operator^ (const Eigen::Matrix& operand1, const Eigen::MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& other) {     return Eigen::Matrix3d{ operand1 * other.transpose() };   }

Comment: Good idea, that has to work! Will let you know soon. Just to cover my bases I can implement a symmetric version, in case parsing is done from right to left.

Comment: Surprisingly the friend function didn't work. Will update if I have any new findings. The error message is identical as before.